# awk to remove lines that finish with a character

Tags: awk

I have a string:

| COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| PRE | test1/ |
| PRE | test1/ |
| PRE | test1/ |
| 2023-01-27 | 12:37:16 |
| 2023-01-27 | 12:37:16 |
| 2023-01-27 | 12:37:16 |
| 2023-01-27 | 12:37:16 |
| 2023-01-27 | 12:37:16 |

Want left a black space with awk the complete lines that finish with the character "/" but i cannot guess it.

I test it for example but doesn't work:

`awk '{gsub("*/",""); print $1 $2}'`

Thanks!

Comment: No, the delimiter is a space.

Comment: `grep -Ev '.*/$' file.txt`

Comment: I can't quite follow, you say you "have a string" and then follow that up with a table. Then, your choice of tags also rather confuses than clarify things. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Note that `gsub("*/","")` does replace *literal* `*/` as there is nothing before `*`

Comment: the subject mentions removing lines, but the `awk` code remove characters; what exactly are you looking to remove? please update the question with the expected result

Comment: are you sure the last field ends with a backslash? what if the last field ends with a backslash + white space? should the line be left alone or should the backslash *plus the white space* be removed?

Answer (score 2):

Use the pattern expression to run different code depending on whether the line ends with `/$` or not.

```
awk '!/\/$/ {print $1, $2}
     /\/$/ {print ""}' filename
```

Comment: I need awk because are columns and doesn't work with your method.

Comment: Ok it works but i need that the line will be a blank space instead of skip it, it's possible? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You said you wanted to delete the entire line, that's what I thought you wanted.

Comment: Sorry I explainned wrong. I want to change that line by a black space because i have a array that uses the result and need that the lines have correlation. Sorry !!!

Comment: I understand, I already updated the answer based on your last comment.